# EditText next Button keyboard

Tags: java, android

i have a layout which the user need to write his detailes in some editText which placed in a vertical linearLayout.

however, everyTime the user need to open the keyboard, write something on the editText and then to click on the back button in android and again click on the next editText and write his detailes and again over and over.

i want to implement that instead of opening and closing the keyboard, instead of the enter button on keyboard i will have a next Button that after the user entered his detailes on a spesific EditText , it will skip to the next EditText without closing and opening the keyboard every time.

i saw that there is some apps that has this feature, however i didnt find how can i implement it

thanks alot

here is the example of my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="283dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/aaa"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="aaaa" >

            <requestFocus />
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/bbb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_back"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="bbb" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cccc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="ccc" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailTextGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_back"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="ddd" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fff"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_back"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="fff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yyy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="yyy" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eeee"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_back"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yyyy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="iii" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ooo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_back"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ppp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="ppp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sss"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_back"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />



    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a very good Documentation for this:

[nextFocusDown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:nextFocusDown)

If I understand you correctly this tab order is exactly what you need.

Comment: do i need to add to every EditText the field:  android:android:nextFocusDown ="+@id/next_editText_id   ?  thanks alot

Comment: yes the next one do you want to activate... works fine for me.

Comment: thanks alot, i will try it, also, where does locate the next Button? instead of the enter button on the keyboard?

Answer (score 7):

You should add in the `XML` file an attribute to your `EditText`s:

`android:imeOptions="actionNext"` .

The next button will bring the user into the next field that can receive input.

Comment: thanks alot, do i need to add it, to all the editText in my layout?

Comment: Yes, you need to add this line to every EditText.

Comment: It's not supporting for android 2.3.6. How to make it work? @EmilAdz

Comment: Thanks man ! I have been trying with nextFocusDown for ages, but it did not work

Answer (score 3):

this is how my editText is and it has the next button and does is

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/typefish"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:singleLine="true" />
```

the one after it or the last one also has

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answer, do i need to add this line: android:imeOptions="actionDone" to every editText? thanks alot

Comment: so, how does it know to skip from the first editText to the second editText?

Comment: im guessing that android:imeOptions="actionDone" on the last editText makes the editTexts before it know that there are others after it untill the last one in which case editing text would be done